# cUrl - getting the html response body

Tags: php, curl

I'm sure this is fairly simple. I'm using the function below to retrieve sites raw html
in order to parse it. during my testing, I decided to run my code on stackoverflow.com

Instead of getting the html response the Chrome is printing out the actual site rather then assigning the html to its veritable. What am I missing?

```
function get_site_html($site_url) 
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 4);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site_url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    global $base_url; 
    $base_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
    $http_response_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    curl_close ($ch);
    return $response;
}
```

> The site raw html should be assigned to $response, and then return it.

Comment: please use spaces for proper indentation on stack overflow.

Comment: What you've posted looks fine.  Are you sure it's not a problem elsewhere in your code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code works. Try `echo htmlentities($response);`  You'll get the raw html for the site you're curling.