# Gettting body with PHP when response code is 201

Tags: php, http, http-response-codes

I need to interface with a REST webserver. When I issue a request, it responds (correctly) with HTTP response code 201 (Created), and the relevant information (JSON object) in the body.

I can verify it using cURL.

I'm trying to get the body it via PHP's `file_get_contents` function, specifying a correct context object, with the following code:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
     'http' => array(
       'method' => 'POST',
       'header' => $header,
       'timeout' => 10.0,
       'content' => $body,
            'ignore_errors' => true
      )
    )
);

$answer = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

However the function always returns a false value and I cannot get the returned body.

What can I do? (I'd rather not call cURL from PHP)

Comment: php has curl methods itself. no need to call curl from shell. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134546/curl-getting-the-html-response-body.

Comment: file_get_contents should return you the body. Perhaps your request is failing for some reason.

Comment: Even better, [Guzzle](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/guzzle) is a very good wrapper around curl.

Comment: You can advice him to use curl or Guzzle but it does not answer why file_get_contents does not work as expected (and it should work!).

Comment: perhaps i've found it
the http context options provide the clause ignore_errors

Comment: Perhaps I've found it.
The http_context_options provide the clause 'ignore_erros',
however this is valid starting from http version 5.2.10
i'm currently using version 5.1.2  ...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've found it.
The cause was an old php version, 
that did'nt handle the 'ignore_errors' parameter.
Switching to a more recent version of php, now it works.