# How to get websites source code in to webpage as result using PHP

Tags: php, html, generator

I want to get some website source code into webpage as result using php.

Here is my html code.i want to add php code to checkout website source code as result.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <form method="post">
            <h1>Website source code</h1>
            <input type="text" name="url" placeholder="Website Url"><input type="submit" value=">>">
        </form>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my php code to export html source code.

```
[[-- <?php $all_lines = file('example.com/'); 
foreach ($all_lines as $line_num => $line) { 
    echo "Code.-{$line_num}: " . htmlspecialchars($line) . "\n"; 
} ?> --]] –
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Can you elaborate?  Perhaps provide an example of an attempt you've made and your intended results?

Comment: Example preview : https://i.imgur.com/EoJQfKG.png

Comment: And what have you tried?  Sketching an image of your intended UI is certainly a *start*, but it's hardly an attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: Here is my php code to export html source code.  [[--


<?php
$all_lines = file('https://www.example.com/');
foreach ($all_lines as $line_num => $line)
 {
  echo "Code.-{$line_num}: " . htmlspecialchars($line) . "\n";
 }
?>   --]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the HTML source code of an URL, you can use cURL :

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com");
$html= curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo htmlspecialchars($html);
?>
```

more info here [cUrl - getting the html response body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134546/curl-getting-the-html-response-body) and here [php: Get html source code with cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592270/php-get-html-source-code-with-curl)